# Is the SCIP solver multi-threaded in PULP?

Tags: pulp, scip

When I run the cord below at Jupyter-notebook,

```
solver = SCIP_CMD(path=scip_file, threads =7)
```

it returns the following error.

```
SCIP_CMD.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'threads'
```

I checked the git-hub code but I could not find the keyword "threads" .
Is the SCIP solver multi-threaded in PULP now?
I downloaded SCIP ver 8.0.3 and pulp ver 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCIP is by default single-threaded, which you could have figured out by searching [previous asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537388/use-of-threads-in-scip)

Comment: Thanks! Looking at the following website, it seems that multithreading is possible. But is it difficult?
https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html#pulp.apis.SCIP_CMD

Comment: You can set that all you want in from the pulp-end. SCIP is single-thread only (unless you use UG as an external parallelization framework, but I don't think you will be able to do that from pulp)